# How can I determine whether a particular piece of hardware is WHQL certified?

Tags: windows

I have been trying to find out which motherboards and graphics cards have been WHQL certified for Windows 7 but I can't find a definitive (searchable) list. Searching for WHQL in Google just deluges me in lots of NVIDIA driver links.

Does anyone know whether there is an up-to-date searchable list of hardware which has been WHQL certified?

Comment: You know that it is not the hardware, but the drivers which are whql certified, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no public list of all whql certified drivers overall. Every driver in windows update is certified, but due companies don't have to upload their certified drivers into windows update, there are many more.
If you wan't to know if a specific driver is whql certified, you may have a look into the windows update driver list, or ask the provider of the driver.